# iOS AVPlayer Entering the foreground will play automatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer

I use AVPlayer to play video.I haven't added any NSNotifications yet.
When the app goes into the background, video will pause, which is what I expected. But when the app goes back to the foreground, video will play again. And I'm going to pause video, and then I'm going to go back in the background, and then I'm going to go back to the foreground, and video is going to play again. Why is that?
1. Why does video automatically play when it enters the foreground from the background? I didn't do anything...
2. What should I do? Getting video from the background into the foreground does not play automatically

Comment: did you find a solution for this ?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

use  the below fun to make the video pause when going into background.

`func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication)`

Comment: I used this method later and paused the video to get the program into the background. But when I turn on the audio of other apps or adjust the volume of the iPhone, I open my app again. The video will continue to play automatically.
Do you know what the reason is?
I obviously paused the audio. What caused it to continue playing again?

Comment: @EddieWu , did you figure out the issue?